# How to get all serial port com in silverlight application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-5.0

I have vs 2012, and I want 2 get all serial port of the computer,
For this I have written code as

```
  //  com = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("ComInterOp_SeeLevel828_Utility");
           com = AutomationFactory.GetObject("InteropComObjects.IO.Ports.SerialPort");
            dynamic count = com.GetDeviceCount();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            List<dynamic> devices = new List<dynamic>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                devices.Add("COM" + i);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                devices.Add(com.GetDevice(i));

            }
            cmdSerial.ItemsSource = devices;
```

But I am getting error in the line

```
com = AutomationFactory.GetObject("InteropComObjects.IO.Ports.SerialPort");
```

as No object was found registered for specified ProgID.